# Facing RPM build error on version update

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

Any idea about this RPM build error? I am doing version update and re-run RPM build.
My `SOURCES` dir has a tar called `electric-fence_2.1.13-0.1.tar.gz` and patches, which i don't want to change the original tar but only added patches.

This is the error:

```
eFence]$ ~/rpmmacros/rpmbuild arm-linux-gnueabi-arm SPECS/target-reltool-electric-fence.spec 

RPM Package building for CE Linux 6.0
Building target platforms: arm-linux
Building for target arm-linux

Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2742

+ umask 022
+ cd /home/raj/eFence/BUILD
+ cd /home/raj/eFence/BUILD
+ rm -rf electric-fence-2.1.14
+ /bin/gzip -dc /home/raj/eFence/SOURCES/electric-fence_2.1.13-0.1.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0

+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd electric-fence-2.1.14

/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2742: line 31: cd: electric-fence-2.1.14: No such file or directory
    error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2742 (%prep)

RPM build errors:
     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2742 (%prep)
```

Here is my spec file extracts at different important parts:

```
enter code here
12 Version: 2.1.14
13 Release: 06000001

18 Group: %{abc_group}
19 URL: http://perens.com/works/software/ElectricFence/
20 Source0: electric-fence_2.1.13-0.1.tar.gz
21 

51 %setup -q -n electric-fence-2.1.14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've told RPM that you are building 2.1.14 and that the archive contains a directory called `electric-fence-2.1.14` but the archive doesn't contain that directory.

Given that the archive is `electric-fence_2.1.13-0.1.tar.gz` I would guess it actually contains a directory called `electric-fence-2.1.13` or something.

Comment: I renamed the archive to 2.1.14.tar.gz

Comment: What you call the archive is completely irrelevant - what matter is what is *inside* the archive - when you unpack it, what directory is created?